# Websites for Baby information and storage of baby-related documents?

Tags: website

is there any website providing a free service which can handle baby information and  baby important days and baby photos , video storages and documents  ?

Comment: Baby storage, you say?

Comment: Is baby information that special? Why not store it on some service that just stores any kind of documents?

Comment: what is baby storage ?

Comment: All Baby information in a single website

Comment: All right. If you want baby storage, you got it.

Comment: @Manni - Happy ?

Comment: Me? I'm not the one that seems to be asking for baby storage. Use whatever you prefer.

Comment: @Manni - what is problem wit you ? why you are always fighting with me and giving comments . just want to know . Personally I don't know you and you don't know anything about me ? why always some shouting all my questions or answers . Please tell what cause you to think about me again and again and again ? and agin ?

Comment: Who's fighting? I edited your question so you don't look like an idiot. That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [hiraj](http://hiraj.com/)

> Hiraj.com offers parents with a safe website to record their child's first movements, first steps, crawl and their everyday journey. Hiraj.com is truly personalized just about the child, letting you combine and arrange all their information in a single place. It is simple to use, easy to share and it's Free!

- [KidMondo](http://www.appvita.com/2009/02/27/kidmondo-your-online-baby-journal/) (and other alternative references)

```
Practical Uses:
1. Document everything about your new parenting journey
2. Share information about your baby with family and friends 
   spread across the globe rather than emailing or mailing photos 
   and news updates
3. Create a memorable and professional-looking scrapbook 
   documenting your baby’s life
```

---

<sup>Related references: [Parent Web 2.0 Tools and Applications](http://www.go2web20.net/#tag:parent)</sup>

Comment: Excellent Nik !! I am exactly looking for this :-)

Comment: Don't forget to backup your baby's life (seriously)!

Answer (score 1):

[TotSpot](http://www.totspot.com/) lets you: "Create a private website about your baby, toddler, or child, and share it with friends and family."

Edit: Also, [Keepaboo](http://www.keepaboo.com/) - "Keepaboo enables you to collect, preserve and share the precious moments of your child's life"